# Will having a patent ensure admission to a top Master's program in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, united-states, patents

Will having a patent get me admitted to a top Master's program in the US?

I am Computer Science background student.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean: "Will they *necessarily* admit me once they verify that I have a patent?" the answer is certainly **no**.  Having a patent -- any kind of patent -- does not certify superior undergraduate level coursework or suggest successful navigation of graduate-level coursework.

If you mean: "Will having a patent have a significant positive effect on my application?" then the answer is **It certainly depends on what the patent is for**.  If it is for something directly related to master's level coursework in the CS departments at one of these institutions: probably it will be distinctly helpful, yes.  If not: maybe not, though it shows some scientific gumption.

Comment: Agreed. There are some extremely ridiculous and useless patents out there.